# SwiftUI: How can you make your app come to the front when clicking on the dock icon of the app?

Tags: swiftui, appdelegate, dock

When a SwiftUI app is minimized and the dock icon is clicked. The app won't be deminimized and put to the front just like other apps do.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
        // THIS IS NEVER CALLED!!!
        if !flag {
            for window: AnyObject in sender.windows {
                window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Other delegate methods like applicationDidLaunch do get called so its not a linking issue. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

**Comment on Asperi**
[image]

Comment: I use Xcode Version 13.3.1, macOS 12.3.1 so about the same. I choose Xcode > File > New Project. Choose macOS tab. App (template). Name the project 'Sample'. Then build and run. When I minimize the app and then click on the App Icon, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry I see the window does come to the front just not restored when minimized. I should clarify in my question, my apologies.

Comment: It may be a bug looking at this report: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/246

Answer (score 4):

## 2022

Will display app in case of it is hidden or minimized both!

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSApp.unhide(self)
    
    if let wnd = NSApp.windows.first {
        wnd.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        wnd.setIsVisible(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In delegate methods that get called when clicking on the dock icon try calling

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

This should bring your app to the foreground

Comment: Did this not solve my problem. I tried every app delegate and none is called when pressing on the dock icon, but even when I put this on a method which get called in other situations this won't put the window in front. Thanks for your comment tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use did become active callback, tested as worked with Xcode 13.3 / macOS 12.2.1

Like,

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    if NSApp.windows.compactMap({ $0.isVisible ? Optional(true) : nil }).isEmpty {
         NSApp.windows.first?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}
```

[Test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOSApp.swift)

*Note: in case of active application the only `application(Will/Did)Update` are called in click Dock icon.*

Comment: Hi Asperi. If it works on your computer it might be a bug in MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258) or Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a), because I run the exact code you shared and it did not work. Unfortunately I am not able to share the image in the comment so I placed it in my question. Please take a look. When I click on the app icon it does not get deminimized as you can see.

Comment: Hmm... I might imagined different scenario, because as I see you don't switch app after window minimised. Try instead with `applicationDidUpdate` callback.

Comment: applicationDidUpdate will fire constantly meaning it will never deminimize. What did work was with the delegate method `applicationDidBecomeActive`. But the app needed to resign first in order for it to work so it's not optimal, but at least a start.

Comment: I just encountered this bug, how fancy of Apple.

Comment: rdar://FB11057969 filed

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary work around that works for me

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    // disable tabs ...
    NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false
}

// Quit if the main window is closed
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    BzLogger[Self.self].info("")
    return true
}

func applicationDidUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
    if NSApplication.shared.mainWindow == nil,
       let event = NSApplication.shared.currentEvent {
        if event.type == .systemDefined {
            // FIX-ME: kdeda
            // This is hack since Apple broke this whole thing on macOS
            
            // BzLogger[Self.self].info("NSApplication.shared.currentEvent: \(event)")
            // BzLogger[Self.self].info("NSApplication.shared.currentEvent: \(event.subtype)")
            // BzLogger[Self.self].info("NSApplication.shared.pressedMouseButtons: \(NSEvent.pressedMouseButtons)")
            // BzLogger[Self.self].info("NSApplication.shared.isActive: \(NSApplication.shared.isActive)")
            if NSEvent.pressedMouseButtons == 1 {
                // mouse down, maybe there is a better way
                if NSApp.windows.compactMap({ $0.isVisible ? Optional(true) : nil }).isEmpty {
                    NSApp.windows.first?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.

In your @main entry class App add this property:

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate: AppDelegate
```

It now should looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, create the AppDelegate class (you can create a new separate AppDelegate.swift file or just continue typing after the App struct closed:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidChangeOcclusionState(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let window = NSApp.windows.first, window.isMiniaturized {
            NSApp.hide(self)
        }
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSApp.windows.first?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}
```

Now it is minimizing, maximizing, closing and reopening again as normal as other apps (ex. Safari, Mail, etc.).

This works perfectly on Monterey 12.4.